# executar git pull sem solicitar senha

Tags: git

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de  eu armazenar a minha senha em cache para o meu usuário do git para que não seja solicitado a senha toda vez que eu realizar um git pull do servidor , lembrando que eu não tenho permissão de alterar as configurações do servidor

//Atualização

Utilizo command line via shell do linux  e não estou utilizando git hub  o git server esta instalado em um server e sempre solicita senha no momento do pull

Objetivo eu tenho um Shell Script que atualiza 5 projetos de uma vez mas ele solicita 5 vezes a msma senha gostaria de passar algo por parametro tal como
git pull origin master --nopassword
ou git pull origin master --password 12345

Comment: Você está usando um terminal comum ou algum aplicativo? No terminal normalmente você só precisa colocar a senha uma vez por sessão.

Comment: Você utiliza o repositório no github?

Comment: atualizei as informações

Comment: veja se `expect/send` te resolve: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16007759/1001109

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem comando pra guardar senha temporariamente: `git config credential.helper cache`, ou comando pra guardar a senha de forma definitiva: `git config credential.helper store`. O primeiro guarda as credenciais em `cache` por 5 minutos (padrão). O segundo guarda permanentemente.

A diferença entre um e outro é o risco de segurança: se você não é o único a acessar o computador, talvez `git config credential.helper cache` seja melhor, pois suas credenciais não ficarão expostas a outros usuários da máquina depois que vc terminar suas edições.

Determine o modo de armazenamento das credenciais: `git config credential.helper store`ou `git config credential.helper cache`.

Na próxima vez que fizer um `git push`, suas credenciais ficarão armazenadas.

Fontes: [git-credential-store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store), [git-credential-cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache).

Answer (score 2):

Lembrei que já tive esse problema e encontrei a solução aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7773605/1001109

Pode ser porque você está com a URL errada, usando `https` ou `git` ao invés de `ssh`:

A URL correta:

```
git@github.com/username/repo.git
```

Outras comuns mas que podem gerar esse erro:

```
https://github.com/username/repo.git
git://github.com/username/repo.git
```

Comment: atualizei as informações